# how to pass bash variable as ssh-keygen argument?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to do this

```
REPO="wordpress-sites" ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/${REPO}_rsa -C "${REPO} deploy"
```

but `REPO` shows as `""`

If I do `export REPO="wordpress-sites"` then `REPO` is set permanently which I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `VAR=value <command>` makes `VAR` available in a command's environment, but the shell doesn't see it when it's performing variable expansion. If you want the shell to see it you have to set it in a separate statement. You can run everything inside a subshell if you want to prevent the variable from leaking to the rest of the script.

```
(REPO=wordpress-sites; ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/"$REPO"_rsa -C "${REPO} deploy")
```

(Notice that I didn't use `export` since it's only a shell variable. It doesn't need to be exported to `ssh-keygen`'s environment.)